# Alternatives to PHP's FTP functions

Tags: php, csv, ftp

I'm trying to write a script that will connect to a FTP server, go to a directory and fetch the newest file in that dir. That file is a CSV file with some warehouse stock data. The idea is then to read the CSV and do some SQL updating.

Now, I've immediately run into problem - our host has not activated the PHP FTP functions (big shared hosting, switching not an option unfortunately). Running `function_exists(ftp_connect)` returns false.

Are there any alternative methods for what I want to do? Could I perhaps use some kind of `ftp://user:paswd@ftp.server.com/folder` syntax? `CURL`?

Comment: is ftp available as a transport?

Comment: @DevZer0 I'm not quite sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: check this line in `phpinfo()` Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip

Comment: Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip

Comment: then you can use `file_put_contents` also to save ftp file

Comment: But I don't know the filename of the file I want to fetch. I have to scan that dir and get the newest file.

Comment: use sockets and do it manually like a pro!

Comment: @Dave I want to be a pro! Please teach me, great keyboard commander!

Comment: @jimmy http://www.raditha.com/php/ftp/partII.php start here has full code + explainations read through it a couple of times before copy and pasting so you understand whats happening

Comment: @Dave This looks interesting, might be the solution. But I am a notorious quick-fix-copypasta person, we'll see how much I learn... Thanks!

Comment: Its easy tbh FTP is pretty much as simple as it gets for socket connections only thing I can think thats easier is telnet based stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First check if FTP is available using this function.

```
is_dir('ftp://user:password@example.com/dir/');
```

If it returns **FALSE** then have a look through the below suggestion.

Without **FTP** it is kinda difficult. But here are some ideas.

If the **CSV** file publicly available from the host. You could download it with `cURL` and then convert the **CSV** file to **JSON** array and then you can modify the required data using the `key=>value` array loop.